# Change language in chrome using a javascript extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a made an extension with the following javascript code to change the preferred language of my browser:

```
// overwrite the `languages` property to use a custom getter
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'language', {
  get: function() {
    return ['en-UK'];
  },
});
```

Printing the language via

```
var lang = navigator.language
```

Yields en-UK, however when I visit https://panopticlick.eff.org/results?aat=1&dnt=111#fingerprintTable I am still appearing as if I prefer en-US. I am using Chrome, how do I modify the code of my extension so I can change my preferred language to en-US?

EDIT: For completeness sake following is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "JavaScript Injection",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["injected-javascript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```